# Javascript - Selecting options not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that can select option from dropdownlist when user entered a value.

For example: enter value `880520` would actually choose `Year:1988 Month:May Day:20`.
[image]

The javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function completeDOB() {

var x = document.getElementById('textvalue').value;

var str = x.match(/.{1,2}/g);

var day = parseInt(str[2],10) +1;
document.getElementById("dob-day").options[day].selected=true;

var month = parseInt(str[1],10) +1;
document.getElementById("dob-month").options[month].selected=true;

var year = parseInt(19+str[0],10);
document.getElementById("dob-year").options[year].selected=true;
}

</script>
```

I'm using `onblur` for the textfield to execute the `completeDOB` function.

```
<input name="textvalue" type="text" id="textvalue" onblur="completeDOB()">
```

However, the selected options only works on the `Day` and `Month`, but the `Year` don't work.
The dropdownlist code for `Year`:

```
<select name="dob_year" id="dob-year">
      <option value="">Year</option>
      <option value="">----</option>
      <?php
        $date = (int) date('Y');
        $numYears = 100;
        for ($i=$date; $i >= $date - $numYears; $i--) {
            echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
        }
      ?>
</select>
```

Also, I've checked the source code of the page and the option value is fine.

```
<option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1985">1985</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1983">1983</option><option value="1982">1982</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1980">1980</option><option value="1979">1979</option><option value="1978">1978</option><option value="1977">1977</option><option value="1976">1976</option><option value="1975">1975</option><option value="1974">1974</option><option value="1973">1973</option><option value="1972">1972</option><option value="1971">1971</option><option value="1970">1970</option><option value="1969">1969</option><option value="1968">1968</option><option value="1967">1967</option><option value="1966">1966</option><option value="1965">1965</option><option value="1964">1964</option><option value="1963">1963</option><option value="1962">1962</option><option value="1961">1961</option><option value="1960">1960</option><option value="1959">1959</option><option value="1958">1958</option><option value="1957">1957</option><option value="1956">1956</option><option value="1955">1955</option><option value="1954">1954</option><option value="1953">1953</option><option value="1952">1952</option><option value="1951">1951</option><option value="1950">1950</option><option value="1949">1949</option><option value="1948">1948</option><option value="1947">1947</option><option value="1946">1946</option><option value="1945">1945</option><option value="1944">1944</option><option value="1943">1943</option><option value="1942">1942</option><option value="1941">1941</option><option value="1940">1940</option><option value="1939">1939</option><option value="1938">1938</option><option value="1937">1937</option><option value="1936">1936</option><option value="1935">1935</option><option value="1934">1934</option><option value="1933">1933</option><option value="1932">1932</option><option value="1931">1931</option><option value="1930">1930</option><option value="1929">1929</option><option value="1928">1928</option><option value="1927">1927</option><option value="1926">1926</option><option value="1925">1925</option><option value="1924">1924</option><option value="1923">1923</option><option value="1922">1922</option><option value="1921">1921</option><option value="1920">1920</option><option value="1919">1919</option><option value="1918">1918</option>
```

And I really have no idea why only the `Year` list wont work but the other 2 works fine.

Updated:

I've tried entering select options manually and turns out the program recognize the option value as following :

```
<option value="03">2018</option>
<option value="04">2017</option>
<option value="05">2016</option>
etc.
```

How would I do to solve the problem? Does the option value must start from 01 ?

Comment: You have no `option` with value of `88` above. When `year` is `88`.

Comment: you have to enter `1988` instead of `88` or add update in your php code `echo "<option value=\"substr($i, 2)\">$i</option>";`

Comment: edited the code above, I did adding `19` infront, and its not working also

Comment: I've edited some findings in the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `options` is a [HTMLOptionsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection). You actually access `options` by their **index** there for `day` and `month`, instead by using their value.

Luckily for you, I bet your day and month selectElements have their **0th** index defined, therefore the next ones indexes match with your `day` and `month` value.

However, this will not work for your `year` selectElement. 
You will need to select the correct `option` element based on its year value, and set its `selected` to be `true`.

**E.g.**

```
function completeDOB() {
  var x = document.getElementById('textvalue').value;
  var str = x.match(/.{1,2}/g);

  var day = parseInt(str[2],10) +1;
  document.getElementById("dob-day").options[day].selected=true;

  var month = parseInt(str[1],10) +1;
  document.getElementById("dob-month").options[month].selected=true;

  var year = parseInt(19+str[0],10);
  var year_options = [].filter.call(document.getElementById('dob-year').options, function (opt) {
    return opt.value == year
  });
  if (year_options && year_options.length) {
    year_options[0].selected = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my life ! Has been finding solution for hours, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Glad it helped.